# How to fix uiimageview in uitableviewcell is resize when scroll table?

Tags: iphone, ios

My code is

```
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[medium fullThumbnailURL]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"missing"]];
    [cell.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
```

[image: Begin]

But when scroll down and back to top again.

[image: After scroll]

How to fix this. Please help.

[Edit]

I crate table cell like this

[image: Cell]

Comment: Can you show how you are creating the cell in tableview?

Comment: Specifically show if you are using the re-use pool and where you are configuring the cells after asking for an existing one.

Answer (score 20):

I've been having the same problem and I finally figured it out! UITableViewCells have their own imageView property which they seem to style in an inaccesible manner. My solution was to use a different instance name for my own UIImageView so that any instances of UITableViewCell wouldn't style it themselves.

Comment: Someone should really mark this as the answer... its correct

Comment: Yeah, cagey is right, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14214337/135913

Comment: Seriously this should be the correct answer. It was this simple and it has taught me a valuable lesson. Worked instantly. I just renamed imageView to imageContainer and it worked.

Comment: Great. Wasted 1 full day on this. Thanks for posting the answer!

Answer (score 3):

You need to scale the image to required size using this method

```
-(UIImage*)scaleTheImage:(UIImage*)image
{
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(70, 70); 
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
    UIImage *scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return scaledImage;
}
```

Comment: fixed this issue for me!